# 2.1.8 You have no items in your shopping cart

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart, magento-2.1.8

When I add the **items into cart,** I'm getting the message saying

> "You have no items in your shopping cart".

I can see the following error in my browser console:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.indexOf')

in `section-config.js`. I can see the below function returning empty.

> getAffectedSections: function (url) {

Not sure what exactly I'm missing. There are no references to localhost. Admin has got all the necessary **Base/Secure BASE URLs**.

Comment: did you try other browser ?

Comment: yes, I tried Safari as well and the same issue occurred.